# How to change error color for TextInput in 'react-native-paper'

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

There is no documented *error* style in [theming](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html) or [TextInput](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html) documentation for **'react-native-paper'**
So the question is how to change the *color* for *error={true}* for TextInput in 'react-native-paper'?

Comment: So what are you actually asking? I'm confused.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 3):

The example without wrapping in

```
<PaperProvider>
 <App />
</PaperProvider>
```

is here:

```
import { TextInput, DefaultTheme } from 'react-native-paper'
.....

return (
.....

 <TextInput
  value={...}
  .....
  theme={{
   ...DefaultTheme,
   colors: {
    .....
    error: '#B22D1D', //any color
    .....
   },
   fonts: {
    .....
   },
  }}
  .....
/>

.....
)
```

Comment: Sorry but is this an answer to your question or an additon? I can't tell

Comment: On stackoverflow we can ask question and provide the answer it at the same time (in case a user knows the answer but cannot find the question), so yes, this is the answer